# How to know if landlord actually owns the property in Paris?

Tags: real-estate, scams, france

I'm looking to rent a flat in Paris and I had some doubts if some people showing me the flats actually own the properties. I fear that someone could scam me by illegally subletting me a flat or even worse subletting me a flat from AirBnB that was available for them for only a few days. How could I verify if the person showing me the property is the legal owner? Is the ownership of a property a public information in France?

Comment: There's an answer to this on a different SE site. Hopefully it helps: http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/3156/proof-of-property-ownership-for-a-landlord-in-france